# Could the moon's centrifugal force generate the same acceleration as 9.8 m/s$^2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, estimation, centrifugal-force, moon

If one dug into the moon, could one reach a point where the centrifugal force is close to that of Earth's gravitational pull? If so, how deep would one have to dig? If not, how close could one get to an acceleration of 9.8 m/s$^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centrifugal force will decrease as you move towards the center of the moon, not increase.$^*$ So this would not be possible, as the centripetal acceleration is not even $9.8\,\rm{m/s^2}$ at the moon's surface.

---

$^*$The centrifugal acceleration from a reference frame rotating with the moon is directly proportional to the square of the angular velocity of the moon $\omega$ as viewed from an inertial reference frame, and is also directly proportional to the distance from the center of rotation $r$, so then $a_c=\omega^2 r$

Comment: How fast would the moon have to rotate to achieve this kind of centrifugal force if the lunar base was just below the surface?

Comment: @A.Kvåle If you ask that out of a plan to give the Moon a huge amount of additional rotational KE to that end, it would be orders of magnitude more feasible to have spinning cities.

Comment: @J.G. I see, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

For motion in a circle of radius $r$ at angular speed $\omega$ radians per second the magnitude of the acceleration due to centrifugal force is
$r \omega^2$.

Since $\omega$ is the same for everything that rotates at the same speed as the Moon, the acceleration due to centrifugal force actually gets *smaller* as you get closer to the centre of the Moon, since $r$ decreases.